# Is Paramiko going to be ported over to Python 3.x?

Tags: python, ssh, python-3.x, paramiko

Seems to be that PyCrypt is required to be ported, in order to make that happen.  Is it hard to do yourself?

Comment: The author of paramiko alone can tell when it will be ported. So is with pyCrypt. If you can't wait, you should help by contributing to it. This seems a off topic question for this forum.

Comment: A bit late for the OP, but might be useful for others: [Paramiko 1.13 has Python 3 support](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/16).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [2to3](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html), which comes with Python 2.7, to convert the source of projects to Python 3 compliant code. Then, just run some tests on the packages you converted and see if they work.

Most of the major work will be done by 2to3, and after that you can make fine-tuned adjustments if you need to to make everything work well.

As for Paramiko and PyCrypt being ported over to Py3K, probably not. The last release of PyCrypt was in 2007 and the last release of Paramiko was in November 2009. So, you'd be best off trying to do it yourself (and, of course, sharing the results with the rest of the world!).

Comment: I've never used 2to3, but have seen it.. wondering why if it's so easy no one else has done it before.  Is there no demand for 3.X versions?  is there an alternative to it ?  Thanks Rafe

Comment: To be pedantic, paramiko requires "pycryto", not "pycrypt".  pycrypto has been updated regularly, and the last release was Aug 2010.  As of Jan 2011, Python 3 support is in the process of being merged into the master repository.