# sys.path and modules - Python3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

I compiled Python 3.2 and tried to run the script below:

```
#/opt/python3/bin/python3
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages')
print(sys.path)
import os
import paramiko
```

The output is:

```
['/home/web.script/scripts/radar_python', '/opt/python3/lib/python32.zip', '/opt/python3/lib/python3.2', '/opt/python3/lib/python3.2/plat-linux2', '/opt/python3/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload', '/opt/python3/lib/python3.2/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./check_log_radar2.py", line 6, in <module>
    import paramiko
ImportError: No module named paramiko
```

The ls command show this:

```
ls /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages

Alacarte
cracklibmodule.so
dogtail
easy-install.pth
easy_install.py
easy_install.pyc
easy_install.pyo
elementtree
GMenuSimpleEditor
gmenu.so
iniparse
invest
libsvn
paramiko-1.7.5-py2.4.egg
paramiko-1.7.7.2-py2.4.egg
pirut
pkg_resources.py
pkg_resources.pyc
pkg_resources.pyo
pycrypto-2.6-py2.4-linux-x86_64.egg
rpmUtils
setroubleshoot
setuptools
setuptools-0.6c5-py2.4.egg-info
site.py
site.pyc
site.pyo
sos
svn
urlgrabber
yum
```

Why the error if the paramiko module is on my path?

Comment: paramiko is installed under python2.4 and not python3.2

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that Python searches the python path directories for either a directory named paramiko with a `__init__.py` file in it, or a `paramiko.py` file. Neither exists.

There is more to it, have a look here http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

In addition, have a look at this (closed) question on: 
[Is Paramiko going to be ported over to Python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973947/is-paramiko-going-to-be-ported-over-to-python-3-x)

As well as this thread https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/16

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the paramiko module on your path, you have the paramiko egg on your path!setuptools makes some magic to allow accessing eggs, but that only works for the python it has actually been installed in. If you want this to work you have to add the path in the egg which contains the module to your sys.path. But obviously it's better to install paramiko into your pyton3 or to use virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

The `ls` is showing us the Python 2.4 installation, but your script is running 3.  What is in your Python 3 site-packages?